# Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am MAC OS X Yosemite I have done all the export tutorial to set the android_home but non of it working for me

Comment: What's the path for your local SDK copy?

Comment: Did you find the solution ????????????? it is really weird ! please help :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Making sure ANDROID_HOME is exported and adding the SDK tool directories to PATH should be more than enough to get you going.*

---

#### Using the terminal

```
# First, we make sure we have a newline at the end of the .bash_profile
echo >> /Users/abdi/.bash_profile

# We set the ANDROID_HOME value in the .bash_profile
echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/abdi/adt/sdk" >> /Users/abdi/.bash_profile

# We alter the PATH value a bit as well
echo "export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" >> /Users/abdi/.bash_profile

# We then tell the terminal to update all the things
. /Users/abdi/.bash_profile
```

---

#### Using a GUI (mostly)

You can also open the .bash_profile file in TextEdit using the `open -e /Users/abdi/.bash_profile` command. If you get some errors about missing files, try running `touch /Users/abdi/.bash_profile` and retry the open command. In the file that opens, add the following lines at the end.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/abdi/adt/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Running `. /Users/abdi/.bash_profile` as in the terminal version after that should get you fully set up.

Comment: the varaibles seem to be set but my command line still returning same error

Comment: Okay, after confirming the .bash_profile file has the two lines at the end, try closing and re-opening the terminal window so that it updates all the things for sure. If that doesn't work, please provide the output of `echo $PATH` and `ls /Users/abdi/adt/sdk`.

Comment: So this what am experiencing now ANDROID_HOME  is for one terminal but not the others when I want to run for example sudo commands will send me error of android_home not seet

Comment: I would suggest trying to manually run the `export` commands by themselves in the terminals that are not working if it is not feasible to restart them. Not 100% sure, but I believe `sudo` messes with env vars as well. Why are you using `sudo` anyway?

Answer (score 7):

First need to set the ANDROID_HOME directory
look into your android-sdk-linux(mac) directory and look for 'android' executable file, generally it will exists under 'tools' directory

so edit your .bashrc from home folder

and add this line down there

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux
PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Once done, exit your console and run your command again

You could expect an error saying  " Please install Android target "android-19" " if it is not set yet.

you may fix that running "android" command and selecting "Android 4.4.2 API 19" to install.

And afterwards, don't forget to give ample permission to directory where the application resides.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Luckily it is easily fixable. Just follow the next few steps (Command-line from terminal).

1. Open the bash_profile file using command line arguments with -

   `vi ~/.bash_profile`

OR

It is possible to open bash_profile in TextEdit and make changes there. Use the following command to do this -

`open -a "TextEdit" .bash_profile`

2. Check if ANDROID_HOME has been set in this file. If it has been already set, delete it (probably wrong). Also check if PATH in this file has any reference to tools or platform-tools (of the android sdk). You'd be better off deleting these before you start typing the following commands.
3. Set ANDROID_HOME correctly using the following command
    `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/adarsh/android-sdk-macosx`

^this is my command because I installed it in that location. Please replace "adarsh" with your username and "android-sdk-manager" with the name of your android sdk folder that you downloaded. Do not copy-paste this command.

For example, if your username is "John" and you the android sdk folder you downloaded and installed is in "Downloads" and you changed your folder name to "sdk", then your command would be -

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/John/Downloads/sdk`

4. Set PATH with the following command

   `export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH`
5. Refresh your bash_profile to set all the changes we just made by typing the command

   `source ~/.bash_profile`

You should be good to go now and begin developing with ionic!Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One source of this problem comes from sudo. If you're sure you've set $ANDROID_HOME correctly then try the following:

```
sudo visudo
```

then add

```
Defaults    env_keep += "ANDROID_HOME"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the env variable you exported is `ANDROID_HOME` and not `android_home` (case sensitive).

After you export, test it by typing

```
> echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

The result should point to the dir where you installed the SDK.

Last but not least edit your `/etc/paths` to add dirs `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` or `/Users/abdi/adt/sdk/platform-tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` or `/Users/abdi/adt/sdk/tools` to the list. Save file. You might need to edit this file as admin if need be. Close terminal and then Open new terminal. Then type

```
> echo $PATH
```

to check if the path is updated.

And then voila, when you type

```
> which android
```

you should see the correct path to the binary returned which in your case is `/Users/abdi/adt/sdk/tools/android`. you should be all set now.

Comment: this returns -->/Users/abdi/adt/sdk where my sdk is

Comment: So i have followwed these steps which android returns my android path and ANDROID_HOME returns my android path but terminal to run my commands it still returns same error

Comment: Modifying /etc/paths seems fairly invasive. We can't even guarantee other users will have read rights to the directories referenced.

Comment: > but terminal to run my commands it still returns same error --> may be you need to close that terminal and launch a new one.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here solved my problem completely. My Node version was little bit old and ionic was giving a warning to upgrade node. After upgrading Node, I had to delete the project and again create the project, then perform all the steps. Hope this helps somebody.