# Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH on OS X

Tags: android, cordova, terminal, android-sdk-tools, cordova-cli

I am getting this error in terminal when attempting to execute this command:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

I read these answers here:

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701176/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

[ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216081/android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-phonegap)

however I don't know where to place the code they provide.

I am running OS X.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Option 1**

for windows

Right click on My computer -> properties -> Advanced system setting -> Environment Variables

Now Edit Path on system variables to

```
;/yourSdkHome/tools;/youSdkHome/platform-tools
```

**Option 2**

In Windows machine, Open Command prompt and enter each of this commands one by one

```
set ANDROID_HOME=**C:\\android-sdk-windows**

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

In MAC Machine, open Terminal and enter these one by one

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

---

Note - `C:\\android-sdk-windows` should be replaced by the path of Android SDK in your machine.

`<installation location>` should be replaced by the path of Android SDK in your machine.

**Example**

in MAC machine, if install location is `~/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk`

first line should be

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I am running on OSX :)

Comment: I know get this

Error: ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existant path: //android-sdk-macosx
    at /Users/xxxx/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:162:19

Comment: @PeterStuart, Find the path of Android SDK by using the search in MAC machine and set that path

Comment: I cant find it in the search, am I missing something daft?