# How to download Android sdk and set android_home path on Windows?

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic-framework, environment-variables

When I download from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html, I am getting the .exe file, and I'm having trouble setting the path. How to set the path ANDROID_HOME on Windows? When I build the ionic app I'm getting the below error

```
[Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. 
If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Comment: Lots of info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful

Answer (score 1):

For windows:

Right click on My computer -> properties -> Advanced system setting -> Environment Variables

Now Edit Path on system variables and append at the end of the line:

```
;C:\yourSdkDirectoryLocation\tools;C:\yourSdkDirectoryLocation/platform-tools
```

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894416/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-on-os-x)

Comment: can you please provide a link to download the sdk directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about your error, but if you're trying to change a value in PATH variable (Windows) [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and I would appreciate some more information about your issues.

Comment: I have downloaded the ionic project using cli and now I am trying to build an apk out of it. While using the command "ionic build --release android" I'm getting the above error